# Square instead of rounded corners in UITableViewCell grouped style

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, cell, tableview

I want to have square corners for my grouped tableview cells instead of the default rounded corners, and I don't just want to use an image to give that effect. Is it possible?

Comment: why not customize a UITableviewStylePlain?..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most simply, in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds] autorelease];
```

Comment: omit the autorelease call in ARC land.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the UITableViewCell's `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` to a custom UIView you create yourself.  That should give you a square cell.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answers works well, but unfortunately removes the separator lines between cells. If you have a 3x3 pixel TableCellBackground.png, with the top two rows of pixels white and the lowest third row grey (to match the separator color), you can do:

```
    // To square the corners, we replace the background view of the top and bottom cells.
    // In addition, the top cell needs a separator, which we get from TableCellBackground.png.
    UIImage *stretchableImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TableCellBackground.png"];
    UIImage *cellImage = [stretchableImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    imageView.image = cellImage;
    cell.backgroundView = imageView;
```

Answer (score 0):

First set your cell's background view as desired and then set the cell's selected background view (to the same bounds as of cell's background)

you can specify the `cornerRadius` property , so that you can set rounding of corners as desired , i have omitted this property in my case

Here is the code to both :

```
        UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.980 green:0.988 blue:0.984 alpha:1];
        bg.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.827 green:0.827 blue:0.835 alpha:1].CGColor;
        bg.layer.borderWidth = kCellBorderWidth;
//        bg.layer.cornerRadius= kCellBorderRadius;
        cell.backgroundView = bg;

        // to make cell selection square and not round (which is by default)
        UIView *bg_selected = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        bg_selected.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        bg_selected.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.827 green:0.827 blue:0.835 alpha:1].CGColor;
        bg_selected.layer.borderWidth = kCellBorderWidth;
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bg_selected;
```