# UITableViewCell with rectangular corners in grouped style

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want rectangular corners on my cells. 
I implemented

```
     cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
```

as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695129/square-instead-of-rounded-corners-in-uitableviewcell-grouped-style), but when I tap the cell, the highlight has still rounded corners... How can I get rid of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
```

Comment: thanks, looks good - do you have any idea which color the highlight has? It's lighter than blue...

Answer (score 0):

... and to mimic the highlight, you'd have

```
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0. green:0.545 blue:0.941 alpha:1] CGColor], [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.027 green:0.353 blue:0.878 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
    [cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

It's not perfect - still checking why it draws over the right boundary of the cell in portrait and does not scale in landscape when I rotate the device...

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Have you tried setting the autoresize masks to flexible height and width?