# How to make a beautiful Tableview like Facebook ios app or tumblr app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview

As shown in pictures below:

I want to make the `UITableView` of my app to look clean and unique just like these two apps.
Is this achievable by `UITableView`? I guess I might have to use "Sections" . Is this correct? If anyone can provide link to a tutorial for creating these kinds of UIs, or 3rd party code would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

[image: facebook]
[image: tumblr]

This is what I have done so far. I want the cell to look isolated .

[image: squak app]

Comment: Have you tried to implement it? There are lots of ways and you certainly do not need third party code.

Comment: Yes, my app is almost finished. I just want to make tableViewCell looks isolated and easier to read. The answer by Anil seems to be a good example to do this. I guess I need to make cell size smaller.

Comment: Try Section.,very easy and nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fb-gallery) cocoa control and make your own

[FB Gallery](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fb-gallery)

These are table views with custom cells. You can sub class the `UITableViewCell` and customise it according to your needs

Comment: The links don't work.

Answer (score 4):

Kong,

There are many ways to implement this.  To give you a start, though, each of these are examples of "grouped tableviews."  You can set your tableview to this style in the storyboard.  From there, you can modify the UITableView's background color to whatever you want (left is gray, right is some shade of blue).  You can add [the square effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695129/square-instead-of-rounded-corners-in-uitableviewcell-grouped-style), and do any number of things to make your views more beautiful.  Each section represents a different grouping and you can modify each cell in a section to present different information differently by registering each cell with a re-use identifier in a storyboard (for example, status update cell versus album presentation view above) and present the appropriately formatted cells when you need them.  The sky's the limit!

Comment: That's a great answer. Thanks Adam.