# iOS: how to create facebook like wall or newsfeed in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am working on an iOS app in which i have to create a wall/newsfeed similar to facebook's newsfeed with all the option like, comment, share.
the main problem is i went to so many websites to get any useful solution how to create it. I am using `UITableView` with custom Cells with UIImageView and other options in it. but if any person post any Post which does not have any image in it the `UIImageview` shows blank space.

Please someone help me to sortout this problem

I also tried this question: [How to make a beautiful Tableview like Facebook ios app or tumblr app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583638/how-to-make-a-beautiful-tableview-like-facebook-ios-app-or-tumblr-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a beautiful Tableview like Facebook ios app or tumblr app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583638/how-to-make-a-beautiful-tableview-like-facebook-ios-app-or-tumblr-app)

Comment: You mentioned you tried the link Luke Patterson suggested.  What went wrong when you did this?  How have you tried to debug it, and what did you find?  What code is relevant to the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Here it is an example that could help you. It will help you make what you want https://github.com/AaronBratcher/UserFeed

Comment: not working it gives: The file “UserFeedTests-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Comment: Probably the project folder isn't enough. You've downloaded the folder?